# Развёртывание (deployment) файла перевода для QtWebEngine

Tags: qt, qt5, qtwebengine

При загрузке вебстраницы в `QWebEngineView` не получается увидеть по правой кнопке мыши перевод элементов контекстного меню. Всё исключительно на английском.

Пробовал, согласно [справке](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-deploying.html), перетаскивать папку "qtwebengine_locales" в папку приложения, пробовал добавлять файл "qt.conf" с различными вариантами опций, но ничего не помогает.

Как корректно подключить перевод "ru.pak" для того чтобы `QtWebEngine` смог его обнаружить при запуске программы?